# Does betweenness centrality for Twitter, considers both followers and following?

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

I'm working on finding the betweenness centrality for a set of users on Twitter.

Betweenness centrality is considered as the proportion of a node appearing in the shortest path between 2 nodes

I'm confused as to whether the keyword "path" or "edges" means the followers or following or followers of the user who he is following. I'm planning to use jgrapht, but I'm not clear about the concept.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Betweenness centrality measures the proportion of **shortest paths** that pass through a node. Since the meaning of a **shortest path** is slightly different between **directed** and **undirected graphs** you should first think of how you wish to represent the data as a graph.

Without further context for your specific use-case, it is more natural to represent the Twitter graph as a **directed** graph, where each user is represented as a node, and edges go from each user to all users followed by that user. Of course given 2 nodes *u* and *v* it is possible to have 2 directed edges (*u*,*v*) and (*v*,*u*) if both users follow each other. Hope that explains the meaning of an edge.

When referring the term "path" in the context of betweenness centrality computation, the meaning is a single **shortest path** between some 2 nodes in this directed graph.

## **Example:**

Say we have 4 Twitter users identified as 1, 2, 3 and 4.
Say 1 follows 2 and 4, and 2 follows 3:
[image]

Then if we use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/), we can compute the betweenness centrality as follows:

```
import networkx as nx
DG = nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 4)])
print(nx.betweenness_centrality(DG))
```

And get:

```
{1: 0.0, 2: 0.16666666666666666, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0}
```

Meaning all nodes except node 2 have a zero betweenness centrality, and node 2 has a value of 0.16667. 
This is the value we get because we have exactly one shortest path that passes through node 2 (from 1 to 3), N=4 and `(N-1)(N-2) = 6`.
To understand better how `nx.betweenness_centrality` works you can take a look [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality) at the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration, but I do have the understanding of the concept of betweenness centrality, What I would like to know is how that applies to Twitter data. Maybe a short example would help me.

Comment: Added an example to the answer, hope it is clearer now.